# Sub menu for a (single) page

Tags: menus, pagination

I am looking for a way that let's me subdivide a page with a pagination-like menu. However, I want to name the menu-items (no numbers...) and don't want the entire page to refresh when clicking on a menu item. Ideally, each sub page would be represented as a separate page but I would also be OK with inserting some separators into the page.

Are you aware of a way/plugin to achieve this?

Comment: There's probably a dozen ways to do this but I think what you're after is dynamically loading content parts using AJAX.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.